# Objective-C valueforKey

Tags: objective-c, nsdictionary

I am using an NSDictionary to store a set values and I am trying to assign them to a double. However I am not sure what to do, valueforkey returns an id which is a pointer. I have tried using the '*' get the actual value but that does not work.

This is the code

```
tempBrain.operand = [variables valueForKey:[(NSString*)obj  stringByReplacingOccurencesOfString:VARIABLE_PREFIX  withString:@""]];
```

tempBrain.operand is a setter method for a double variable. Variables is my NSDictionary.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming the value stored is an `NSNumber` you can use `doubleValue` like this:

```
tempBrain.operand = [[variables objectForKey:[(NSString*)obj  stringByReplacingOccurencesOfString:VARIABLE_PREFIX  withString:@""]] doubleValue];
```

Note also I have changed `valueForKey` to `objectForKey`, which is the correct method to use to get an object from an `NSDictionary`.

Comment: Both `valueForKey:` and `objectForKey:` will work. The former simply has more restrictions on what can be done with it (only string keys, no reserved characters, etc.).

Comment: @Justin, thanks for pointing that out. Explains why a key '@' kept crashing my program.

Answer (score 1):

NSDictionary can contain only objects of NSObject subclasses.

Try do this:

```
NSMutableDictionary *dic = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:10];

// Add object
[dic setObject:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:3.0] forKey:@"Third"];

// Read object
double val = [[dic objectForKey:@"Third"] doubleValue];
```

Answer (score 0):

I get it now, it returns an object so I should send the doubleValue message to it.

Comment: Excellent! And welcome to Stack Overflow. If you are satisfied with one of the answers given, you should accept it (by clicking the 'tick' next to it). That way, the question gets marked as answered, you get rep and the answerer gets rep.